# Remove characters from the end of a string up to a character in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, parsing

For example, say we have the string "hello/world/of/stacks" and we want to remove "/stacks" from it (everything up to the last '/'), to be left with "hello/world/of". This needs to work for any string with /'s in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that `rpartition` works quite well in this situation:

```
s = 'hello/world/of/stacks'

p s.rpartition('/').first #=> "hello/world/of"
```

Or, if you want to be fancy:

```
s, = s.rpartition('/')

p s #= > "hello/world/of"
```

Comment: Nice (+1). I think ruby classes have a method for just about any single function one can imagine. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `rindex` and `[]` methods from String:

```
input.str[0, input.rindex(?/)]
```

Comment: just don't mistake it with `string[a..b]`. That takes from-to range. I say about `string[a, b]` that takes from-length.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.dirname("hello/world/of/stacks")
# => "hello/world/of"
```

Comment: This is really the way to go if it is a path you are working with!

Answer (score 0):

```
1.9.3p448 :024 > str = "hello/world/of/stacks" 
 => "hello/world/of/stacks"
```

You can then find the last index of the slash in the string using `rindex`...

```
1.9.3p448 :025 > str.rindex("/")
 => 14
```

Then using that index, you can grab only the characters up to (and excluding) that slash...

```
1.9.3p448 :026 > str[0..(14 - (str.length + 1))]
 => "hello/world/of"
```